# textbox change apostrophe to html code

Tags: asp.net

When I set textbox.Text with data contains apostrophe from a gridviewrow, it change the apostrophe to &#39.  For example, the data in my database showing 40' and it shows 40&#39  instead when I assign to the textbox.  How do I decode it?  Thanks for any help.  Here is my code.

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = GridView1.SelectedRow;

    textbox.Text = row.Cells[1].Text;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **[HtmlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmldecode%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)** from the HttpUtility class..

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = GridView1.SelectedRow;

    textbox.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(row.Cells[1].Text);
}
```